# Como alterar background ao mudar a orientação de tela no Android

Tags: android, background, orientation

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Android onde a imagem de fundo só fica legal quando o celular fica na vertical. Eu gostaria que toda vez que o usuário mudasse a orientação de tela o background mudasse para uma imagem que fique legal sem ficar toda esticada.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [Changing view background image on orientation change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003688/changing-view-background-image-on-orientation-change)

Comment: Veja a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/multiscreen/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia usar uma imagem vetorizada, mas caso não queira basta fazer o seguinte:

1º => mude a visualização do seu projeto de "android" para "project".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2º => Depois crie na pasta "res" as pastas **drawable-land** e **drawable-port**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicione seu background na **vertical na pasta drawable-port** e o **horizontal na pasta drawable-land**.

**OBS => COM O MESMO NOME!!!**

3º => Tanto o seu background horizontal quanto o vertical devem ter o mesmo nome, para no .xml da activity você fazer o seguinte:

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Com isso quando o aparelho estiver na vertical, será exibida a imagem contida no drawable-port e quando for mudado para a horizontal aparecerá a imagem contida no drawable-land.

Sobre fazer 2 backgrounds, um na vertical e outro na horizontal tome o seguinte como exemplo:

horizontal (**1280x720**):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

vertical (**720x1280**):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Basta fazer uma media queries para ele. 
Tipo:

// Orientação na horizontal

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
```

background-image: URL(image-horizontal.PNG)
}

// Orientação na vertical

@media all and (orientation: landscape) { background-image: URL(image-vertical.PNG) }

Pelo entendi eh isso :)